# How to normalise a 2D FFT plot to the right frequency (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 2d, fft

First, refer to [How to plot temporal frequency as a function of spatial frequency from a MATLAB FFT2 output of a time-space image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722506/how-to-plot-temporal-frequency-as-a-function-of-spatial-frequency-from-a-matlab) for a bit more of a background to this question.

Assuming in the case of this sample signal:-

```
n = [0:1024];
signal = sin(2*pi*n/10) + sin(2*pi*n/20) + sin(2*pi*n/30);

N = 2048; %At least twice of the n value
X = abs(fft(signal,N));
X = fftshift(X); %normalise data
F = [-N/2:N/2-1]/N; %normalise data - shift it to the correct frequency
plot(F,X);
```

The variable F range here is what sorts out the normalisation of the x-axis from

[image]

to the following

[image]

However, I'm struggling to figure out a way to normalise the x and y-axis values for a 2D FFT plot (The image for the plots are available on the above given link at the first sentence of this post.)

Does anyone have a clue as to how I should go about doing this?

A snippet of a working portion of my codes are:-

```
clear;

deg_speed = 15.35; %degrees visual angle/sec
max_speed = deg_speed/5.15; %converting the required deg_speed in terms of frames
nr_of_dots = 10; %number of dots
sin_cycle_dur = 80; %number of frames (along Nt) required to complete a sin wave.
sineTOTAL = 0;

Nx = 160; % Frames along x-axis. 1 frame = 0.1 dva
Nt = 200; % Frames along y-asis. 1 frame = 10ms

start_dot_pos = round(rand(1,nr_of_dots) .* Nx); %spawn random starting positions of dots
dot_pos = zeros(Nt, nr_of_dots); %Initialise 2D stimulus array
dot_pos(1,:) = start_dot_pos; %Fill up first line of 2D array with the starting position of dots

dot_pos_sim = zeros(Nt, nr_of_dots); %Setup simulated array so the final dot_pos can be scaled to mean speed of outher condition
dot_pos_sim(1,:) = start_dot_pos; %Fill up first line of 2D array with the starting position of dots

for a = 2:Nt
    sine_speed = max_speed .* sin((a-1) / sin_cycle_dur *2*pi); %Sine formula
    sineTOTAL = sineTOTAL + abs(sine_speed); %Add all sine generated values from Sine formula to get an overall total for mean calculation
    dot_pos_sim(a,:) = dot_pos_sim(a-1,:) + max_speed .* sin((a-1) / sin_cycle_dur *2*pi); %Sine simulated matrix (before scaling)
end

%Ignore this for loop for now. This is later required for normalising simulated
%array to the mean speed across other conditions.
for b = 1:Nt
    dot_pos(b,:) = dot_pos_sim(b,:);
end

dot_pos = round(dot_pos); %Frames are in integers, therefore all float values needed to be rounded up.
dot_pos = mod(dot_pos,Nx)+1; %Wrap the dots the go beyond the edges to the other side of the plot

%For all of the slots filled with dots, set the value from 0 to 1.
for c = 1:Nt
    stim(c,dot_pos(c,:)) = 1;
end

figure (1)
x=linspace(0,16,5);
y=linspace(0,2,10);
imagesc(x,y,stim); 
xlabel('degrees');
ylabel('seconds');
colormap('gray');

X = abs(fft2(stim));
X = fftshift(X); %normalise data
X = log(1+X);
figure (2)
imagesc(X);
colormap('gray');
```

I have been trying to find guides and help online but to no avail so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I'm not sure about axes and scalings, I go back to basics: the complex exponential (a complex sinusoid, with real=cos and imaginary=sin).

I know that the 1D FFT of `exp(j * 2 * pi * f * t)`, for a vector of time samples `t` (in seconds) and a frequency `f` (in Hz) will have a peak at `f`, as long as `fmin < f < fmax`, where `fmax = 1 / diff(t(1:2)) / 2` and `fmin = -1.0 * fmax`, and that the peak will have value **1.0**.

The exact same thing applies in the 2D case. A 2D complex exponential with frequency `(fx, fy)` will have peak at `fx` and `fy` in the respective axes, and the peak value will be **1.0**.

Here's a complete Matlab example that works through the details and conventions to get this known result. It simulates a 2D complex exponential with x-frequency at 2 Hz and y-frequency at -3 Hz over a rectangular 2D grid. Then it takes the FFT after zero-padding.

```
clearvars

x = linspace(-2, 2, 100); % seconds
y = linspace(-3, 3, 200); % seconds

xFreq = 2; % Hz
yFreq = -3; % Hz

im = exp(2j * pi * y(:) * yFreq) * exp(2j * pi * x(:)' * xFreq);

figure;imagesc(x, y, real(im))
xlabel('x (seconds)'); ylabel('y (seconds)');
title('time-domain data (real)')
colorbar; colormap(flipud(gray))

Nfft = 4 * 2 .^ nextpow2(size(im));
imF = fftshift(fft2(im, Nfft(1), Nfft(2))) / numel(im);

fx = ([0 : Nfft(2) - 1] / Nfft(2) - 0.5) / diff(x(1:2));
fy = ([0 : Nfft(1) - 1] / Nfft(1) - 0.5) / diff(y(1:2));

figure; imagesc(fx, fy, abs(imF));
colorbar; colormap(flipud(gray))
xlabel('f_x (Hz)'); ylabel('f_y (Hz)')
title('Frequency-domain data (abs)')
grid; axis xy
```

Here's the input time-domain data:

[image: Time-domain data]

Confirm that you see *two* peak-to-peak cycles in the x dimension and *three* cycles in the y-dimension—it's easy to see these if you study the bottom and left edges of the figure.

Here's the 2D FFT, appropriately shifted (with `fftshift`), with axes scaled correctly (see `fx` and `fy`), and peak scaled correctly (see how I divide the output of `fft2` with `numel(im)`).

[image: Frequency-domain data]

Confirm that the peak is at (2, -3) Hz corresponding to `[fx, fy]`, and that the value of the peak is almost 1.0 (it's a little smaller because of of the quantized grid).

So, there’s three things I did to make all this work:

- `fftshift` the output of `fft2`,
- generate `fx` and `fy` correctly to match the `fftshift`, and
- scale the output of `fft2` by the number of elements it operates on *before zero-padding*.

Hopefully you can extend this complete example to your own case.

Comment: Hi thanks for these! I think I'm getting somewhere with this. The one problem I'm seeing now is that my original stimulus image plot is a lot more complex than a pre-defined -2 and 3 Hz in your example case. The values I'm working with, is that a full sin movement cycle gets completed in 800ms (ie. 80 frames) and the stimulus travelled (at 15.35 deg/s) a total of 15.35/1000*800 degree visual angle within 80ms. I am not quite sure how that can be translated to Hz (physics dummy here), which is important because it defines fx and fy for your example. Have you got an advice for this?

Comment: My intuition tells me to replace the linspace values for x to (0,16,160) and y to (0,2,200) because the x-axis represents a range from 0-16 degrees over 160 columns and the y-axis, 0-2 seconds over 200 rows. Am I right to do so? I've tried this and the y-axis produced a range that is believable (between -40 to 40Hz) but the x-axis produced a range 10 times smaller (-4 to 4) presumably because I defined the x-axis to be between 0-16.

Comment: My goal in showing a complex exponential at (-2, 3) was to confirm that the steps in generating the frequency-domain data were correct. If you make the code snippet into a function that accepts `x`, `y`, and `im` (the horizontal `x` and vertical `y` sampling locations of the time-domain data `im`) and that returns `fx`, `fy`, and `imF` (the horizontal & vertical sampling locations `fx` and `fy` of the frequency-domain data `imF`), these three outputs should be “correct”: correct min/max values for the frequencies, and correct scaling of the freq-domain data. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very simple answer - what you appear to be looking for is a scale along the X and Y axes that represents the normalised frequency.  As you've used fftshift, the DC term will be in the middle of the plot, so your scales should run from -0.5 to 0.5.  This is easily done with the `imagesc(x,y,C)` command, instead of just `imagesc(C)` as you are currently doing.  (You use X, but the Matlab help uses C as it represents a colormap).

Change your second last line to:

```
imagesc([-0.5,0.5],[-0.5,0.5],X);
```

and it gives you what I think you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for this. However I am a little puzzled in that if you refer to the last image of my older thread, I'm not sure how that guy was able to generate axis up to the range of -30 to 30. This is actually my main objective - to be able to convert the raw -0.5 to 0.5 values into the respective temporal and spatial frequency.

Comment: OK - to fix temporal and spatial frequencies you need more information.  What is the spacing of samples in the time and space domains?  If, for example, the spacing of samples in the time domain, delta_t, were 20 ms (corresponding to a sampling rate of 50 Hz), then the corresponding frequency axis would range from -25 Hz to 25 Hz, being +/- 1/(2 * delta_t).  For spatial frequencies, a similar argument applies, except that it isn't measured in Hz (which is cycles per second), but in cycles per unit distance (which may be m, cm, whatever...)

Comment: Oh right, spacing of samples meaning the change from one column/row to the next? So I had 200 rows on the time domain (y-axis) reflecting 2 seconds (10ms per row). That would be +/- 1/(2 * 0.01), giving a range of -50 to 50 Hz?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  The same applies to the spatial domain, though the units are different (obviously)